# What suitable sentence to explain the item cant be deleted?

Tags: error-message

I want to tell the user that this item cannot be deleted because this is the only item left in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message: **"You need to have at least one item in this list."**

Additionally, you can communicate this (im)possibility leveraging on the the Delete button.

- Grey out the Delete button *(that automatically sends the signal)*
- If they still attempt to click on it, you can then show the message.